# Show that if $|a|=1$ or $|b|=1$, then $\left|\dfrac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right|\leq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$, $|a|,|b|\leq 1$, $a\neq b$. Show that if $|a|=1$ or $|b|=1$, then $$\left|\dfrac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right|\leq 1$$

**Proof:** Let $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$, $|a|,|b|\leq 1$, $a\neq b$. Note that $|a|=|\overline{a}|$.

If $|a|=1$, then $|\overline{a}|=1$. This implies $$\left|\dfrac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right|=\dfrac{|a-b|}{|1-\overline{a}b|}\leq \dfrac{|a|+|b|}{|1|+|\overline{a}|\cdot |b|} = \dfrac{1+|b|}{1+|b|} = 1.$$

If $|b|=1$, then $$\left|\dfrac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right|=\dfrac{|a-b|}{|1-\overline{a}b|}\leq \dfrac{|a|+|b|}{|1|+|\overline{a}|\cdot |b|} = \dfrac{|a|+1}{1+|a|} = 1.$$

I was wondering if what I did is correct? I am not confident with my answer because I treated the inequalities of the numerator and denominator like normal  and then just put one over the other.

Comment: Have a look here:  http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/rc476/complexanalysis/autD.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the fraction the increase, then you must *decrease* your denominator to achieve that. Thus, your solution is not correct but there are many ways to solve it. For instance, make observations like $a(1-\bar{a}b) = a - |a|^2b = a-b$ if $|a| = 1$

Comment: So for when $|b|=1$, $b\overline{a-b}=                           
            \overline{\overline{b}(a-b)}=b\overline{a}-1=-1(1-\overline{a}b)$

Comment: My question is then why is there $\leq $?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown equality is still included in $\leq$. It just turns out that  a stronger result, strict equality, was true in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not confident with my answer because I treated the inequalities of the numerator and denominator like normal and then just put one over the other

You are right *not* to be confident since, indeed, you can't divide inequalities. In other words, if $a\le b, c\le d$ it does not follow that $a/c \le b/d\,$. Try for example $a=b=c=1$ and $d=2\,$.

Instead, you can show that if $|a|=1 \iff |a|^2 = 1 \iff a \bar a = 1 \iff \bar a = \dfrac{1}{a}$, then:

$$\require{cancel}
\left|\dfrac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right|=\left|\dfrac{a-b}{1-\dfrac{1}{a}\,b}\right|= \left|\dfrac{\;\;\cancel{a-b}\;\;}{\dfrac{\cancel{a-b}}{a}}\right| = |a| = 1
$$

Since the problem is symmetric in $a,b$ the same applies if $|b|=1$.

Comment: Then how should I do the problem?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Edited into the answer.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Comment: Very nice answer .+1.